# Laptop restart after suspend

Tags: suspend

Recently my Dell latitude E7240 has had issues with suspending. It seems to have come about after a recent update, however I am not sure which or if that is the case.

The laptop will suspend when the lid is closed but after a few minutes it will begin a restart. This is obviously a concern for me as I carry my laptop in a backpack and I don't want it to overheat.

I have played with the lid settings in the dconf editor but nothing helped.

Could it be a hardware problem? The laptop is still under warranty so not is the time to get it checked if it is. However if its a known bug or a software fix that is always easier than not having the laptop for a few days. Has anyone else experienced this?